# c++ throws 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFEEEFEEE. on return from main

Tags: c++, c++11

program creates binary random access file "student.dat" populates file with 6 records then closes the file.  then the file is opened read/write then the 6 records are formatted and displayed. then several records are displayed then updated then displayed again to verify updates "took".  then the file is closed.  when the return is reached that is when the access violation writing location... is generated.  The error pointed to by the debugger is in a system file called xutility line 217.  I have no idea what xutility does. my question is what am I doing to cause this error after the program runs and performs all that it is supposed to do.

Added comments: This error only happens when the file is opened for input. ie ios::in

Here is my main code:

```
/*******************************************************************************
*   CIS-278                                                                    *
*                                                                              *
*   Program Name:       Student_Main_Driver.cpp                                        *
*                                                                              *
*   Author:             Don Register                                           *
*                                                                              *
*   Written:            March 2015                                             *
*                                                                              *
*   Purpose:            Demonstrate the use of random access files.            *
*                                                                              *
*   Modifications:                                                             *
*                                                                              *
*******************************************************************************/

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include "Student.h"

using namespace std;

void displayOutput( Student &);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fstream studentFile;
    studentFile.open("student.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);

    Student student01(1100, "Washington", "George", "Mil", 40, 3.77);
    Student student02(1200, "Jefferson ", "Thomas", "Gov", 45, 3.88);
    Student student03(1300, "Adams     ", "John  ", "Psy", 39, 3.79);
    Student student04(1400, "Franklin  ", "Ben   ", "Sci", 50, 3.89);
    Student student05(1500, "Hamilton  ", "Alex  ", "Pol", 42, 3.85);
    Student student06(1600, "Hancock   ", "John  ", "Pub", 48, 3.81);

    studentFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&student01),sizeof(Student));
    studentFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&student02),sizeof(Student));
    studentFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&student03),sizeof(Student));
    studentFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&student04),sizeof(Student));
    studentFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&student05),sizeof(Student));
    studentFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&student06),sizeof(Student));

    studentFile.close();

    studentFile.open("student.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);

    Student studentNew;

    studentFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&studentNew), sizeof(Student));
    displayOutput(studentNew);

    studentFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&studentNew), sizeof(Student));
    displayOutput(studentNew);

    studentFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&studentNew), sizeof(Student));
    displayOutput(studentNew);

    studentFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&studentNew), sizeof(Student));
    displayOutput(studentNew);

    studentFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&studentNew), sizeof(Student));
    displayOutput(studentNew);

    studentFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&studentNew), sizeof(Student));
    displayOutput(studentNew);

    studentFile.seekg(1 * sizeof(Student), ios::beg);
    studentFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&studentNew), sizeof(Student));
    displayOutput(studentNew);

    studentFile.seekg(2 * sizeof(Student), ios::beg);
    studentFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&studentNew), sizeof(Student));
    displayOutput(studentNew);
    studentNew.setStudentMajorCode("CIS");
    studentFile.seekp(2 * sizeof(Student), ios::beg);
    studentFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&studentNew), sizeof(Student));
    studentFile.seekg(2 * sizeof(Student), ios::beg);
    studentFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&studentNew), sizeof(Student));
    displayOutput(studentNew);

    studentFile.seekg(3 * sizeof(Student), ios::beg);
    studentFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&studentNew), sizeof(Student));
    displayOutput(studentNew);
    studentNew.setStudentCreditsEarned(55);
    studentFile.seekp(3 * sizeof(Student), ios::beg);
    studentFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&studentNew), sizeof(Student));
    studentFile.seekg(3 * sizeof(Student), ios::beg);
    studentFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&studentNew), sizeof(Student));
    displayOutput(studentNew);

    studentFile.seekg(4 * sizeof(Student), ios::beg);
    studentFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&studentNew), sizeof(Student));
    displayOutput(studentNew);
    studentNew.setStudentGPA(3.91);
    studentFile.seekp(4 * sizeof(Student), ios::beg);
    studentFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&studentNew), sizeof(Student));
    studentFile.seekg(4 * sizeof(Student), ios::beg);
    studentFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&studentNew), sizeof(Student));
    displayOutput(studentNew);

    studentFile.close();

    cout << "\n\nPress Enter to continue. . .";
    char ch = getchar();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS; // this is where the error is generated

}  // end of main

void displayOutput(Student &studentNew)
{
    string outPut;
    outPut = studentNew.toString();
    cout << outPut;
}
```

Here is my student.h file

```
// Student.h


#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Student 
{
public:
    Student();  // default constructor
    Student(int, string, string, string, int, double);  // constructor with parameters
    ~Student(); // destructor

    // Setter methods
    void setStudentID(int);
    void setStudentLName(string);
    void setStudentFName(string);
    void setStudentMajorCode(string);
    void setStudentCreditsEarned(int);
    void setStudentGPA(double);

    // Getter methods
    int getStudentID();
    string getStudentLName();
    string getStudentFName();
    string getStudentMajorCode();
    int getStudentCreditsEarned();
    double getStudentGPA();

    string toString();

private:
    int studentID;
    string studentLName;
    string studentFName;
    string studentMajorCode;
    int studentCreditsEarned;
    double studentGPA;

};

#endif
```

Comment: I don't know what your `Student` class looks like but if it includes `std::string` fields or pointers to memory, don't expect happy things when you try to serialize it and then reconstitute it using raw bit representation.  It might be trying to access memory addresses that are no longer valid.

Comment: In your case, probably when the `studentNew` destructor is called.

Answer (score 2):

```
static_assert( std::is_pod<Student>::value, "reading/writing as bytes is only safe and valid if you are a pod type" );
```

will probably fail if you insert it into your code.

The error produced will explain what you did wrong.

Serializing non-pod types requires doing more work than just a reinterpret cast.  You can usually searialize pod types (assuming structure sizes remain the same) that way.  Non-pod types, like `std::string` require custom serialization/deserialization code.